# Observable form callback seems to only fire once

Tags: angular, socket.io, rxjs, ngrx

A little backstory, I have an app that uses a websockets for all major means of communication. To create that socket I have to retrieve a token from localstorage and then connect the socket and authenticate against the server.

But I want to be able to observe socket events immediately, so I made an async socket service that allows me to queue up the socket bindings and execute them once the connection is established. That seemed to work until now, I try to observe `socket.on` with the `Observable.bindCallback` function. That only works once and then never outputs anything again.

#### Code for the socket service is here http://pastebin.com/Mub9zSWQ

I'm calling `socket.observe('likePost').do(res => console.debug(res)).subscribe(res => store$.dispatch(new LikePostReceivedAction(res.user_id, res.post_id)));` from my app component to handle the socket events.

I'm also open for other ideas on how to handle the socket initialization, especially what to do when I have to reconnect the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, for observing the on events I have to use `observeOnce(event: string): Observable<any> {return Observable.bindCallback((event: string, f) =>this.asyncSocket.once(event, f))(event);}` and then just add an `off` method stub to the AsyncSocket to make it an *eventLike* target.